# Was this data available when job was run?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, t-sql, time

This will seem like a dumb question, and you're probably right.

We have an `SSMS` job that runs at *5:30AM AST* every day to download Oracle data from the current day and insert into a `tsql` table. A row in Oracle that I normally download looks like this:

```
Items_Sold
28

Date_Insert
12/12/2017 3:52:57 AM -06:00

Date_UTC           
12/12/2017 7:00:00 AM

DateTime_Zone
12/12/2017 3:00:00 AM -04:00

SalesDate
12/12/2017 3:00:00 AM
```

The job ran successfully but didn't download this particular row. I'm thinking that the data wasn't available when the job ran considering that `Date_Insert` has a `-06:00` hour offset. I do not know where the Oracle servers are.

This is the Oracle query that I use for the `Data Flow Task`. The issue isn't the query, since this has been running successfully for several months. I'm simply posting it as an FYI:

```
SELECT 
SalesDate, Items_Sold
FROM ORACLE_TABLE
where 
SalesDate  >= trunc(sysdate)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a dumb question. Time zones are really confusing! Here is a set of code to help you figure it out. I "think" this explains that you were correct in your assumption that, "the data wasn't available when the job ran." If I've made some incorrect assumptions based on your question and information, maybe this along with the examples I've included will get you started. Happy Coding!

[SQL 2016 has a really cool AT TIME ZONE feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql) that would make this easier, fyi.

```
DECLARE @timestamp_ast      DATETIMEOFFSET = N'12/12/2017 00:05:30:00 AM -4:00'
        , @timestamp_oracle DATETIMEOFFSET = N'12/12/2017 00:03:52:57 AM -06:00';

SELECT @timestamp_ast      AS [timestamp_ast]
       , @timestamp_oracle AS [timestamp_oracle];

SELECT datediff(minute, @timestamp_ast, @timestamp_oracle) AS [minutes_difference];

-- example - if first timestamp is before, there is a  [positive_minutes_difference]
SELECT datediff(minute, N'00:01:00', N'00:02:00') AS [positive_minutes_difference];

-- example - if first timestamp is after, there is a  [negative_minutes_difference]
SELECT datediff(minute, N'00:03:00', N'00:02:00') AS [negative_minutes_difference];
```

Comment: Thanks so much. So you're saying that there's a 118-minute difference between the Date_Insert (12/12/2017 3:52:57 AM -06:00) and the AST hour when the job ran (5:30AM AST) ?

Comment: I'm saying my initial validation says that, but you should double check me. As noted, time zones are VERY confusing! But the code I included is the process I would go through to validate what is going on. I'm mostly afraid I may have misread some of the times based on your information. So double check me and use my code as a starting point for your own validation.